# Unity 3D C# Player Movement Jumping Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have been working on a script to make a ball move on the x-asis with a constant speed but can also be controlled. When I press the space bar to jump. It won't jump unless I press the button like 5 to 6 times. After the ball does jump the first time if you repeatedly tap the space bar it will jump but if you leave it alone and let it roll and then try to jump again. It will not let you. I'm very confused.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Speed : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sspeed = 7.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
    public float gravity = 20.0F;

    private Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {

    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (GetComponent<CharacterController>().isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector2();
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= sspeed;
            moveDirection.x = sspeed;
        }
        else if (GetComponent<CharacterController>())
        {
            moveDirection.x = gravity;
        }

        moveDirection.x -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
        CharacterController player = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        if (GetComponent<CharacterController>().isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = new Vector2();
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= sspeed;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code a little bit better please? It's really hard to read as it is

Answer (score 1):

There a better way of doing that:

```
Rigidbody body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    body.AddForce(transform.up*jumpSpeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConstantMoveByX : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float constantSpeed = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce = 25.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float gravity = 9.8f;

    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    private void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            moveDirection = Vector3.right * constantSpeed;
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection = moveDirection * constantSpeed;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```